# unwanted border line on graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

My ggplot graphs always have this unwanted line on left and top border when I copy  to MS word. Is this related to R or word?

[image: ggplot graph]

Comment: what exactly do you mean by copy? Do you use Rstudios-export plot feature? Do you screen grab them? Do you right click into a chunk-output and select copy plot?

Comment: Looking again the the picture provided, it even looks like the scaling frame from RStudio is shown. I cannot reproduce this. So please describe in more detail what you are doing.

Comment: I use ```export``` and then ```copy to clipboard``` options from R and then past in a word document

Comment: Maybe try `ggsave` function in `ggplot2`

Comment: Thanks @Suren. ggsave works fine, it just adds a couple of extra steps that I was trying to avoid.

Comment: You could use `rmarkdown`, create a template, either barebones (just plots) or a full-featured report (tables, summaries, etc), and use `output: rmarkdown::word_document`.

Comment: For me this works fine. R 3.6.1, Rstudio 1.2.1335, maybe you need to update?  Or it is actually something in the code. Could you provide a minimal example that causes this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way around this:

1. Export -> Copy to clipboard
2. Copy plot as Metafile
3. Paste in Word or PPT

Fonts and lines come out thin but there are no borders.  If you don't like the thin lines you can

4. Right and copy plot in Word or PPT
5. Right click and paste as picture (not as Destination theme)
6. Delete unwanted plot

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem - but it behaves inconsistently across devices.

Upgrading Rstudio worked on my surface, but not my dell 7510 or xps15 - so it appears to possibly have something to do with drivers